# Armazenando informações de alunos

Tags: c, c++, windows

Preciso desenvolver um **programa** em plataforma **WINDOWS** aonde será armazenado **informações sobre alunos** do tipo: **idade**, **turma**, **turno** e **nome**.
O programa deve conter também uma busca por **nome**.
Gostaria de sugestões.

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflowPT. Recomendo que edite a sua pergunta e forneça mais detalhes referente as suas dúvidas. A comunidade está sempre disposta a ajudar, mas temos que ver um esforço partindo de você. Aqui nós não fazemos trabalhos de faculdade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode estar criando um **vetor de estrutura**.

```
#define MAX_ALUNOS 50

struct Alunos
{
    std::string Nome;
    unsigned int idade;

    std::string turma;
    std::string turno;
};

std::vector<Alunos> Hypnos_Alunos(MAX_ALUNOS);
```

E na busca, você pode estar criando uma **função** que recebe uma **string** com o nome do aluno.

```
void Buscar_Por_Aluno(std::string NOME)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < MAX_ALUNOS; x++)
    {       
        if (Hypnos_Alunos[x].Nome.compare(NOME) == 0)
        {
            // Listando dados do aluno encontrado
            std::cout << "Nome: " << Hypnos_Alunos[x].Nome << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Idade: " << Hypnos_Alunos[x].idade << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Turma: " << Hypnos_Alunos[x].turma << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Turno: " << Hypnos_Alunos[x].turno << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```